# How can I configure SSMA to generate a filtered Unique index that ignores NULL?

Tags: sql-server, oracle, unique-constraint, unique-index, sql-server-migration-assi

My business logic relies on the Oracle feature that `NULL` is ignored in a Unique index.

How can I configure SSMA to automatically generate a filtered Unique index that ignores NULL?

Manually, in T-SQL, I could write

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX indunique ON mytable(uuid)  WHERE uuid IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Almost every migration needs tweaking. Tools can do some/a lot of the work, but there are almost always steps that you would have to do yourself. This just appears to be one of them,

Comment: @Larnu  The Release Notes for SSMA v8.9 says: "Generate filtered unique indexes for NULL-able columns", so why not using it?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssma/oracle/what-s-new-in-ssma-for-oracle-oracletosql?view=sql-server-ver15#ssma-v89
But I can't find a corresponding flag in SSMA or the Project Settings documentation: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssma/oracle/project-settings-conversion-oracletosql